# Remove Sprites Faster

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody, enumerate

I'm working on an app which moves a large amount of sprite to the left constantly. Once the sprites are off screen, there are removed and move sprites are added slight off the screen to the right.

At the moment, I have a timer which calls an update func every 0.05 second. In the update func, I use enumerateChildNodesWithName("*") to find any sprites which have left the left hand side of the screen and then I remove them and add more sprites. *The enumerateChildNodes has to run through about 300 sprites, with about 8 sprites being removed/ added every 0.05 seconds.*

Now what I was thinking of doing, is adding a physics body (boundary) past the left hand side of the screen, so that when the sprites make contact with this physics body, then they are removed and more sprites are added.

I've timed the enumerateChildNode option and it is pretty minimal in execution time, but if the physics body (boundary) is faster in execution, I'd prefer to use that, but I'm not sure how I could time this. *Also, my app currently says it uses high battery power, so I don't know if the physics body (boundary) option might reduce this or make it worse.*

Does anybody know which option is better, or if there is a better option then both these options for removing sprites? Alternatively, does anybody know how I would be able to test the performance of the physics body (boundary) option?

Comment: No need to use a timer. Just call `enumerateChildNodesWithName:` in `update:`, and the off-screen sprites will be removed every 1/60 sec.

Comment: Instead of removing the sprites, why don't you just reuse them when they go off the left side of the screen? Can you just set their position off the right side of the screen and update any necessary information? This would save allocating and deallocating a whole bunch of objects.

Comment: @ WangYudong Sorry, that was a typo on my part, the timer needs to be called about every 0.005 of a second, not 0.05. I've actually made is 0.00 and have it not repeat until the update is done (which calls about every 0.005 of a second). When I use the update: it is not fast enough to keep up with the sprites being removed and added.

Comment: @ Mr Beardsley I'd like to do what you have suggested, but unfortunately, most of the sprites are different. So the ones being removed, might not be the same as the one being added.

Comment: Since SpriteKit uses a rendering loop to render each frame, I'm not sure if it is possible to update a frame more than 60 times per second.

Comment: @ WangYudong, maybe we are thinking of two different things, because I just ran a test on a timer (set at 0.00, repeat only after func is complete) vs update: and the func the timer calls was called 487 times for every update call.

Comment: @WangYudong, just letting you know, that I figured out a way of mixing the update: and timer together (I still need the speed of the timer at times, but not all time) and my battery usage has halved and is now running at an average of low, which is great!!!

Comment: I think you can post your solution so as to help more people in the future.

Comment: I would, but I'm not sure if it is removing/ adding sprite any faster, I just think it has improved my battery usage.